Python application bundled with PyInstaller prevents Ubuntu from booting successfully after reboot
I’ve developed a Python application that performs various host-related tasks, such as upgrading packages via apt, downloading and installing apt packages, creating files on the filesystem, and more.
My environment is Ubuntu 22.04/20.04, and I’m using PyInstaller to bundle the application into an executable.
However, I’ve encountered a strange issue: after running the executable and it completes successfully, if I reboot the machine, it fails to boot, and I receive the following errors:
Post Pyinstaller boot error
Does anyone know what might be causing this?
I tried to reboot the machine and expect it to boot successfully

Looks like your boot filesystem is broken. Use a LiveUSB to boot into the "Try Ubuntu" environment. While booted, backup all your data. Check your partitions. Run fsck on your boot and root partitions. Add resulting error output to your question above (those should be cut/paste). There are many possible causes. Might be a poorly-behaved application....or might not.
